# Django project gives me the following error AttributeError: 'SafeExceptionReporterFilter' object has no attribute 'get_safe_settings'

Tags: django

I'm currently creating a wep app using django with react and django toolbar. The same project worked a weeks ago, but now it gives me this error message. This is the first time I'm using django, i have no idea what's the problem.

```
Exception ignored in thread started by: \<function check_errors.\<locals\>.wrapper at 0x0000018E6BC28310\>
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\\Users\\nagyd.virtualenvs\\pythonProject\\lib\\site-packages\\django\\utils\\autoreload.py", line 225, in wrapper
fn(\*args, \*\*kwargs)
File "C:\\Users\\nagyd.virtualenvs\\pythonProject\\lib\\site-packages\\django\\core\\management\\commands\\runserver.py", line 117, in inner_run
self.check(display_num_errors=True)
File "C:\\Users\\nagyd.virtualenvs\\pythonProject\\lib\\site-packages\\django\\core\\management\\base.py", line 376, in check
all_issues = self.\_run_checks(
File "C:\\Users\\nagyd.virtualenvs\\pythonProject\\lib\\site-packages\\django\\core\\management\\base.py", line 366, in _run_checks
return checks.run_checks(\*\*kwargs)
File "C:\\Users\\nagyd.virtualenvs\\pythonProject\\lib\\site-packages\\django\\core\\checks\\registry.py", line 71, in run_checks
new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs)
File "C:\\Users\\nagyd.virtualenvs\\pythonProject\\lib\\site-packages\\django\\core\\checks\\urls.py", line 13, in check_url_config
return check_resolver(resolver)
File "C:\\Users\\nagyd.virtualenvs\\pythonProject\\lib\\site-packages\\django\\core\\checks\\urls.py", line 23, in check_resolver
return check_method()
File "C:\\Users\\nagyd.virtualenvs\\pythonProject\\lib\\site-packages\\django\\urls\\resolvers.py", line 396, in check
for pattern in self.url_patterns:
File "C:\\Users\\nagyd.virtualenvs\\pythonProject\\lib\\site-packages\\django\\utils\\functional.py", line 37, in __get__
res = instance.__dict__\[self.name\] = self.func(instance)
File "C:\\Users\\nagyd.virtualenvs\\pythonProject\\lib\\site-packages\\django\\urls\\resolvers.py", line 533, in url_patterns
patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
File "C:\\Users\\nagyd.virtualenvs\\pythonProject\\lib\\site-packages\\django\\utils\\functional.py", line 37, in __get__
res = instance.__dict__\[self.name\] = self.func(instance)
File "C:\\Users\\nagyd.virtualenvs\\pythonProject\\lib\\site-packages\\django\\urls\\resolvers.py", line 526, in urlconf_module
return import_module(self.urlconf_name)
File "C:\\Users\\nagyd\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39\\lib\\importlib_init_.py", line 127, in import_module
return \_bootstrap.\_gcd_import(name\[level:\], package, level)
File "\<frozen importlib.\_bootstrap\>", line 1030, in \_gcd_import
File "\<frozen importlib.\_bootstrap\>", line 1007, in \_find_and_load
File "\<frozen importlib.\_bootstrap\>", line 986, in \_find_and_load_unlocked
File "\<frozen importlib.\_bootstrap\>", line 680, in \_load_unlocked
File "\<frozen importlib.\_bootstrap_external\>", line 855, in exec_module
File "\<frozen importlib.\_bootstrap\>", line 228, in _call_with_frames_removed
File "C:\\Users\\nagyd\\PycharmProjects\\pythonProject\\firstproject\\firstproject\\urls.py", line 27, in \<module\>
path('__debug__/', include('debug_toolbar.urls')),
File "C:\\Users\\nagyd.virtualenvs\\pythonProject\\lib\\site-packages\\django\\urls\\conf.py", line 34, in include
urlconf_module = import_module(urlconf_module)
File "C:\\Users\\nagyd\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39\\lib\\importlib_init_.py", line 127, in import_module
return \_bootstrap.\_gcd_import(name\[level:\], package, level)
File "\<frozen importlib.\_bootstrap\>", line 1030, in \_gcd_import
File "\<frozen importlib.\_bootstrap\>", line 1007, in \_find_and_load
File "\<frozen importlib.\_bootstrap\>", line 986, in \_find_and_load_unlocked
File "\<frozen importlib.\_bootstrap\>", line 680, in \_load_unlocked
File "\<frozen importlib.\_bootstrap_external\>", line 855, in exec_module
File "\<frozen importlib.\_bootstrap\>", line 228, in \_call_with_frames_removed
File "C:\\Users\\nagyd.virtualenvs\\pythonProject\\lib\\site-packages\\debug_toolbar\\panels\\settings.py", line 7, in \<module\>
get_safe_settings = get_default_exception_reporter_filter().get_safe_settings
AttributeError: 'SafeExceptionReporterFilter' object has no attribute 'get_safe_settings'
```

Hope that i can be advised on this thank you! :(

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this error because my Django version was 2.2.17.

To resolve this issue, you have two options:

1. Downgrade the package version using the following command:

pip install django-debug-toolbar==3.2.4

2. Alternatively, you can update your Django version to 3.1 or higher.

The below code block in debug_toolbar/panels/settings.py within django-debug-toolbar version 3.2.4 is the reason why the error can be avoided:

```
if django.VERSION >= (3, 1):
    from django.views.debug import get_default_exception_reporter_filter
    get_safe_settings = get_default_exception_reporter_filter().get_safe_settings
else:
    from django.views.debug import get_safe_settings
```